# Name for the maximum size of $f^{-1}(w)$

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and $f:X\to Y$ be a function.  Is there a name for the following quantity? $$\sup_{y\in Y}\ \big|f^{-1}(y)\big|$$

I was thinking the "maximal valence of $f$".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would use the word "valence" here!  In any case, you say "let X and Y be sets" but are you **assuming** that these are number sets?  For general set "A" neither | | nor "sup" exists.

Comment: The cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$ certainly exists, though it's not necessarily finite.